# Newly installed application is not shown in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center

I've just installed a *Scribus* application from Ubuntu Software Center and used it a couple of times. Now I want to delete it but I can't find it in the list of installed packages. I have Ubuntu 16.04. 
I can still see it through `sudo dpkg --get-selections` but this is not the best way to manage applications at least for me. So what's the problem with Ubuntu Software Manager in 16.04? It looks quite retarded compared to 14.04.